# Append a data.table to another data.table by reference similar to rbind

Tags: r, data.table

I want to append ("rbind") a data.table object at the end
of another data.table object within a function
without returning the combined result
but appending directly to the first data table object
so that I do not have to assign the function result
to the first data.table again.

Since a data.table is passed by reference as function argument
it could be possible but `rbind` and `rbindlist` do always create
a new result object instead of appending to an existing data.table object.

How can I do this?

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(a = 1, b = "hello")
dt2 <- data.table(a = 2, b = "world")

dt.all <- data.table::rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2))

dt.all
#    a     b
# 1: 1 hello
# 2: 2 world


dt.append <- function(x1, x2) {
  x1 <- data.table::rbindlist(list(x1, x2))  # does not change the outer data.table!
  invisible()
}

dt.append(dt1, dt2)

dt1   # I would like to see both rows here
#    a     b
# 1: 1 hello
```

Comment: You are assigning to 'x1' i.e. in local scope.  The object on the lhs of `<-` is taken literally as 'x1'.  May be you need `assign`

Comment: what you're getting is not modification by reference / editing the table in-place -- instead, just a new table bound to the same symbol/name as the original.

Comment: @Frank Yes, you are absolutely right, I am just reusing the symbol name what is good enough for my problem. I do not know any `data.table` function that could directly append to an existing `data.table` - any hints welcome. I think this could be worth a change request.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a cool feature to have. I don't understand the internals enough to know why it has not been (as far as I know) requested. Fwiw, row deletion by reference is here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to assign it to the object in the global environment.  In the OP's function, it is assigned locally to an object named 'x1' and one of the nice things about functions it that the global objects are not mutated (local scope)

```
dt.append <- function(x1, x2) {
  obj <- deparse(substitute(x1)) # get the actual object name as a string
  assign(obj, value = data.table::rbindlist(list(x1, x2)), envir = .GlobalEnv)

 }

dt1
#   a     b
#1: 1 hello
#2: 2 world
```